# specify function given certain constraints

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory

Let $F:V\rightarrow{}\mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}$ be a function on domain
$V=\{(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})|(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})\in(0,1)^{4},
x_{1}+x_{2}<1, x_{3}+x_{4}<1\}$. Here is what I know about $F$:

(i) $F(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})=0$ if $x_{1}=x_{3}$ and $x_{2}=x_{4}$ (self-similarity).

(ii) $x_{1}=x_{3}$ and $x_{2}=x_{4}$ if $F(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})=0$
(separation).

and the following:

$$
\begin{array}{rlc}
\frac{\partial{}F}{\partial{}x_{1}}\left(\frac{x_{2}-1}{x_{4}-1}x_{3},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}\right)&=&0 \\
\frac{\partial{}F}{\partial{}x_{2}}\left(x_{1},\frac{x_{1}-1}{x_{3}-1}x_{4},x_{3},x_{4}\right)&=&0 \\
\frac{\partial{}F}{\partial{}x_{3}}\left(x_{1},x_{2},\frac{x_{4}-1}{x_{2}-1}x_{1},x_{4}\right)&=&0 \\
\frac{\partial{}F}{\partial{}x_{4}}\left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\frac{x_{3}-1}{x_{1}-1}x_{2}\right)&=&0 \\
\end{array}
$$

What can I tell about $F$?

Background: $F$ is something like a distance measure, but it doesn't
need to be symmetric or obey the triangle inequality. $(x_{1},x_{2})$
is a point in the model for the probability distribution
$x_{0}=1-x_{1}-x_{2},x_{1},x_{2}$ such that $x_{0}+x_{1}+x_{2}=1$.
Symmetry would be
$F((x_{1},x_{2}),(x_{3},x_{4}))=F((x_{3},x_{4}),(x_{1},x_{2}))$. If
two points are equal, their distance is zero, thus self-similarity.
Two distinct points have a positive distance, thus separation. The
differential equations follow from something called Jeffrey
conditioning. I want to know what constraints there are on a function
$F$ that is consistent with Jeffrey conditioning.